# ember different controller for a property

Tags: ember.js, controller

I have a session and a test.
Session holds many tests - so in the model it is a `DS.HasMany`.

The view has a tests table, and I want it to be sortable. 
So the question is - how can I define a `tests` controller to the tests "property" in session

**session.hbs:**

```
<div class="main-container">
    <h1>session {{id}}</h1>

    <table class="tests-table table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Logical ID</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
      {{#each test in tests}}
          <tr>
              <td>{{test.id}}</td>
              <td>{{test.logicalId}}</td>
              <td>{{test.name}}</td>
          </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </table>
</div>
```

**routes/session.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      session: this.get('store').find('session', params.session_id),
      tests: this.get('store').find('test', {
        session_id: params.session_id
      })
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model.session);
    var testsController = this.controllerFor('tests');
    testsController.set('model', model.tests);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1:

For the tests table to be sortable you don't have to provide a tests controller. You can simply do:

```
{{#each test in sortedTests}}
      <tr>
          <td>{{test.id}}</td>
          <td>{{test.logicalId}}</td>
          <td>{{test.name}}</td>
      </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

in your template, and in your SessionController you can do:

```
sortedTests: Ember.computed.sort('tests', 'logicalId'(
```

if you want to sort the tests in order of there logical id, or

```
sortedTests: Ember.computed.sort('tests', function(a,b){
  //your custom sorting function
  a.name >= b.name
})
```

if you want some more complex sorting to happen.

### Solution 2:

If however, you still want to use a dedicated tests controller for your table, simply write a TestsController with your sorting logic, and a tests-template like so:

```
{{#each test in controller}}
      <tr>
          <td>{{test.id}}</td>
          <td>{{test.logicalId}}</td>
          <td>{{test.name}}</td>
      </tr>
  {{/each}}
```

And now, you can do use embers `render` helper in your sessions template:

```
<table class="tests-table table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Logical ID</th>
        <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  {{render "tests" tests}} // this will render the tests template in-place
  // using the testsController backed with tests as its model
</table>
```

The ember docs have [a good read](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/) about that topic

Comment: well... I will have in a future feature, a separate "all tests" screen that the table itself will be actually the same - so I think that solution 2 is better for me. Thanks